# sql query distinct

Tags: sql-server, gaps-and-islands

My database record is as below:-

```
cartid  orderid   foodid   qty
==============================
92      107       5        1
93      107       5        1
94      107       5        1
95      107       11       1
96      107       5        1
97      108       5        1
```

Can it be arrange into this form?
Assume that the max sum(qty)=3

```
foodid   sum(qty)
=================
5        3
11       1
5        2
```

Comment: I believe that you want only 2 first rows, right?

Comment: you need to use group by condition on your sql and on table each record field has different values but the foodid can be use on grouping..if groupping by food id is intended the result should be sum(qty) 5 for foodid 5 and sum(qty) 1 for foodid 11 for Db values that u post

Answer (score 5):

You look like you are trying to sum contiguous ranges (islands) of the same `foodid` ordered by `cartid`?

```
;with cart as
(
SELECT 92 AS cartid,107 AS orderid,5 AS foodid, 1 AS qty UNION ALL
SELECT 93,107,5, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 94,107,5, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 95,107,11,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 96,107,5, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 97,108,5, 1 

),
NumberedCart As
(
SELECT cartid,foodid,qty,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cartid)- 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY foodid ORDER BY cartid) AS G
 FROM cart
 )

 SELECT foodid, SUM(qty) AS [sum(qty)]
 FROM NumberedCart
 GROUP BY foodid,G
 ORDER BY MIN(cartid)
```

Returns

```
foodid      sum(qty)
----------- -----------
5           3
11          1
5           2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by Max Sum(qty)=3...

But here is some SQL to get you started:

```
SELECT        foodid
            , SUM(qty)
FROM        YourTableName
GROUP BY    foodid
```

Comment: I think the subtlety in the question is that there should be multiple rows for a specific foodid where the records are mixed (in order of cartid) with other foodids. e.g. group the sets based on sequence, up until a different foodid

Comment: this is not what maniacCow wants. If you see the results the foodid=5 is appearing twice.